Nuances of these sentences

1週間前から階段の前にバイクが置きっぱなしにしてある。(In book).

What would be difference if I write it like this:

1週間前から階段の前にバイクが置きっぱなしだ。


If you add more context to the "In book" example, the question can become easier to answer.

してある indicates an intentional action. The first sentence means that someone deliberately left the motorcycle in front of the stairs a week ago, and it's still there. The second sentence is a neutral expression that simply says that the motorcycle has been left there for a week. In this situation, the difference between the two sentences is not large, but if you think someone has maliciously left the motorcycle, you'd tend to use the first sentence. If you're worried that someone might have accidentally forgotten their motorcycle, the second sentence tends to be chosen.
The difference is more significant between sentences like 窓が開けっぱなしにしてある and 窓が開けっぱなしだ. The former is used when the speaker perceives someone's intention to leave the window open.

I agree with this answer, tho IMO sometimes a speaker might use してある even if they know the action was unintentional. In this case, they are making accusation against the person who left the window open and/or are being mean.
